# What is the server context of my SCM configuration in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

We are using Jenkins for our CI builds. We use GIT for our SCM (which is actually Gerrit code review), and up until now we were using the git protocol, so there wasn't much security involved. We have decided to start using ssh, but it is not working correctly. When the build tries to pull from the Gerrit repository, we receive errors indicating that the Jenkins user cant be authenticated.

I know in Gerrit we have to set up a user and store the SSH key for the user. What I am not sure about is who that user is.

Obviously we have a Jenkins server, but we also have a different server (a slave of Jenkins) as the Workspace. I am not sure which server is the one that tries to poll Git when the build starts. I have generated SSH keys on both servers, and tried associating both keys with the user in Gerrit, but I get an error either way.

So my question is this: When a build in Jenkins tries to poll from an SCM, is it the main Jenkins server that has to have access to that server or is it the Workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), right?

... so the answer to your question is: both. When you are in the job configuration page then the Jenkins SERVER tries to validate "Repository URL" using the server user and ssh keys. When the job is executed then the Jenkins SLAVE clones the repository using the slave user and ssh keys. The best way to work with Git and SSH (or HTTPS) is to use the "Credentials" feature ([Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)).

Comment: I discovered that the hard way, by looking at the logs and figuring out which ip address was making the request. Still not working for me, but for a different reason. Your answer is correct, thanks!